# Integer receives wrong value from stringv[]

Tags: c, encryption, casting, do-while, caesar-cipher

Caesar Cypher - Basic encryption.

I'd ask for your help to understand why variable k receives negative value even if second command line (argv[1]) equals 3, for example.

```
int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    string text;
    int k = 0;

    do 
    {
        printf("Type in a plain text:\n");
        text = GetString();

//k receives wrong value
        k = (int) argv[1]; 

// Sanity check
        printf ("argv[1] is %s and k is %d\n", argv[1], k);
    }
    while (k < 0);
```

Comment: `string` is no standard type. See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do here is a `conversion` rather than a `type-cast`, hence type-casting to `int` won't help, you need to convert the `char *` to `int` using a library function, like the commonly used `int atoi (const char *str)`, which is defined in the header file `stdlib.h`. Don't forget to `#include` it. !

However, I would suggest using `strtol`, because of it's robust error reporting. It specifies the return value on overflow (returns `LONG_MIN` in case of an `underflow` and `LONG_MAX` in case of an overflow) and also allows the user to set the `base` to be followed during the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just cast the string to an int. You need to actually parse it. You can use the `atoi` function included in `stdlib.h`. You'll need to put:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

at the top of your file and change the line:

```
k = (int) argv[1];
```

to:

```
k = atoi(argv[1]);
```